# turn off Cocos2D verbose logging

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I just upgraded to cocos 2.1, and am seeing a ridiculous amount of logging to the console, such as:

```
2013-09-18 23:15:38.120 Notes and Clefs[842:907] cocos2d: deallocing <CCSprite = 0x1182aa0 | Rect = (816.00,640.00,32.00,64.00) | tag = -1 | atlasIndex = -1>
2013-09-18 23:15:38.121 Notes and Clefs[842:907] cocos2d: deallocing <CCSprite =  0x1182600 | Rect = (816.00,128.00,32.00,64.00) | tag = -1 | atlasIndex = -1>
2013-09-18 23:15:38.122 Notes and Clefs[842:907] cocos2d: deallocing <CCArray = 0x1161e00> = ( <CCSprite = 0x1182790 | Rect = (816.00,640.00,32.00,64.00) | tag = -1 | atlasIndex = -1>, )
etc..
```

From looking at the code, I see:

```
#if !defined(COCOS2D_DEBUG) || COCOS2D_DEBUG == 0
#define CCLOG(...) do {} while (0)
#define CCLOGWARN(...) do {} while (0)
#define CCLOGINFO(...) do {} while (0)

#elif COCOS2D_DEBUG == 1
#define CCLOG(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGWARN(...) __CCLOGWITHFUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGINFO(...) do {} while (0)

#elif COCOS2D_DEBUG > 1
#define CCLOG(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGWARN(...) __CCLOGWITHFUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CCLOGINFO(...) __CCLOG(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif // COCOS2D_DEBUG
```

And I set COCOS2D_DEBUG = 0, but I still get the same verbose logging...

I have Cocos2D in my project as a static library .a file..  Is it possible that this .a already has a macro/constant defined at level 2 or something, and that's why I'm seeing it not make any difference?

Can anyone recommend a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when the static library is compiled using the Debug scheme, it'll print all these debug messages out.  Try recompiling the static library with the COCOS2D_DEBUG preprocessor macro set to 1.

Why are you adding it as a static .a library though?  I just add the cocos2d-ios.xcodeproj to my own project and add libcocos2d.a to Build Phases under Link Binary with Libraries.  That way it'll automatically recompile cocos2d whenever a change occurs.

Comment: A static library is a ".a" file, no?  But-- yeah I am doing it exactly as you described.  I have the cocos2d-ios.xcodeproj in my project, and the .a file is added to the "link binary with libraries" option.  I have a COCOS2D_DEBUG macro set to 0, and have cleaned, verified that the .a product is removed, yet when I build, I still get all the verbose logging output.

Comment: The preprocessor macro is in the cocos2d-ios project under the cocos2d target, not your project.

Comment: ahaaaa.. now that makes sense!